# Confusion regarding bounded contexts and interaction between them

Tags: javascript, java, architecture, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I'm trying to implement my first domain driven application, after going through Eric Evan's book on Domain-Driven Design. I'm a bit confused on how to go about this.

In my application, a user can purchase a service for getting them certain number of views on a video they post in Youtube, which is fulfilled by the other users of my app who watch those videos(Basically a replica of the many youtube promoter apps already available, for learning).

Say the service is represented in the app as an entity called WatchTime aggregate. The WatchTime entity contains some information like the id of user who purchased this service, the max number of views purchased, number of views already fulfilled, and points earned by someone who views the video once.

I decided to go with 3 bounded contexts, one for authentication, one for handling the watchtimes, like adding or removing them, and one for managing users and their data. Now the user has his personal info and some points that he collected while using the application.

At first I was thinking that all the user data and related actions be in the 3rd context, like adding more points to a user and or reducing his points, but then while making the model, I realized that that if the watch time purchasing service is going to be in the second one, then its going to have to communicate to the third one every time a WatchTime is purchased to tell a service there to reduce points for that purchase. It wouldn't make sense to keep them in two different ones.

So instead what I'm thinking of is have a model of the user in the 2nd bounded context, but with only points and the WatchTimes that this user purchased, so now it doesnt have to call something on the 3rd context.

My question is how to properly seperate things into contexts? Is it like based on the models, or should it be based on the functionality, and all models related to those functionality are going to be in the same context?

And another thing, how to ensure that all the objects of the same entity have the same value and properly persisted in the database? Should only one object representing a particular entity be present at a time, which will be persisted and disposed by the end of a function? Because I was thinking that if two objects representing the same entity be present at the same time, there's a possibility of both having different values or changing to different values.

If i sound like im rambling, please let me know if I have to be more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bounded contexts basically define areas of functionality where the ubiquitous language (and thus the model) are the same.  In different bounded contexts, "user" can mean different things: in a "user profile" context, you might have their email address but in the "viewing time" context, you'd just have the points granted and viewership purchased.

Re "another thing", in general you need to keep an aggregate strongly consistent and only allow an update to succeed if the update is cognizant of every prior update which succeeded, including any updates which succeeded after a read from the datastore.  This is the single-writer principle.

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this.  First, you can use optimistic concurrency control and store a version number with each aggregate.  You then update the aggregate in the DB only if the version hasn't changed; otherwise you attempt the operation (performing all the validations etc.) against the new version of the aggregate.  This requires some support in the DB for an atomic check of the version and update (e.g. a transaction).

An alternative approach (my personal preference) is to recognize that a DDD aggregate has a high level of mechanical sympathy to the actor model of computation (e.g. both are units of strong consistency).  There are implementations of the actor model (e.g. Microsoft Orleans, Akka Cluster Sharding) which allow an aggregate to be represented by at most one actor at a given time (even if there is a cluster of many servers).